# Add array conditionally as a variable in an another array conditionally

Tags: php, arrays, variables, conditional-statements, key-value

This is how the final output of the array should look like

```
$dataToReset = array (
    'email_address' => $subEmail,
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'interests' => 
        array (
        '1111111' => true,
        '2222222' => true,
        '3333333' => true,
        '4444444' => true,
        '5555555' => true,
    )
);
```

I want to replace following part

```
'interests' => 
    array (
    '1111111' => true,
    '2222222' => true,
    '3333333' => true,
    '4444444' => true,
    '5555555' => true,
)
```

With a variable `$interestsAdd` like this

```
$dataToReset = array (
    'email_address' => $subEmail,
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    $interestsAdd
);
```

The values that i get and what i have tried is like following, but no success!

```
if ($form_data['lbu_multilistsvalue'] !== ''){
    
    $groupsSelected = $form_data['lbu_multilistsvalue'];
    $selectedGroups = array_fill_keys(explode(",", $groupsSelected), true);

    $interestsAdd = ['interests' => $selectedGroups];

} else {

    $interestsAdd = '';

}
```

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I should get the first part of code in my question

Comment: Not what SHOULD what DO you get.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I get an Array of `key=>value` inside an Array called `'interests'`. if this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, either define the key in the array:

```
$interestsAdd = [1,2,3];

$dataToReset = array (
    'email_address' => 'x',
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'interests' => $interestsAdd
);
```

Or add it afterwards:

```
$interestsAdd = [1,2,3];

$dataToReset = array (
    'email_address' => 'x',
    'status' => 'subscribed',
);
$dataToReset['interests'] = $interestsAdd;
```

Or with your current structure, merge them:

```
$interestsAdd = ['interests' => [1,2,3]];

$dataToReset = array_merge($dataToReset, $interestsAdd);
```

Comment: The second part works for me!! Thanks dear you have saved me couple of hours!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your first array like this:

```
$dataToReset = [
    'email_address' => $subEmail,
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'interests' => [],
];
```

Once you have your $interestsAdd array built you add it to the first array:

```
$dataToReset['interests'] = $interestsAdd;
```